# firebase install error in react-native project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In my react-native project, I have some problems that cannot install firebase in my project like this.

[Error message when I insert firebase code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZoIS.png)

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Card, CardSection, Button } from './components/common';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
      const firebase = require('firebase/app');
      firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: '',
        authDomain: '',
        databaseURL: '',
        projectId: '',
        storageBucket: '',
        messagingSenderId: ''
        });
      }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Thi is Header" />
        <LoginForm />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: per the error; i'd check line #32

Comment: You don't have to import "const firebase = require('firebase/app');" again in componentWillMount method, as you have already imported at the top. Just replace "import firebase from 'firebase';" with "import firebase from 'firebase/app';"

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `import firebase from 'firebase';`

and also use `const firebase = require('firebase');`
instead of `const firebase = require('firebase/app');`